# Does rust have a compile option to insert Several nop instructions before each rust function?

Tags: assembly, rust, rust-cargo, instrumentation, rustup

Like this:
[image]

I want to insert a few nop instructions in front of each rust code, taking up a few instruction cycles. What compilation options can I do?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/macro.asm.html

Comment: You might also be able to use some weird rustc parameter (possibly `-C llvm-args`?) to pass `-fpatchable-function-entry` to llvm.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Note that "a few nop instructions" do not necessary take "a few instruction cycles" to execute on modern microprocessors.

Comment: If I want to do rust's hot-patch function, I need to insert the NOP  instructions before each rust function。

Comment: emmm，The fpatchable-function-entry option seems to be not supported by rust. An error is reported during compilation.